# Neverwinter Nights 1 - Is the Rod of Fast Buffing mod compatible with the GoG version?

Tags: neverwinter-nights

Is the Rod of Fast Buffing compatible with the current GoG copy of Neverwinter Nights Diamond (Build 1.69) on Windows 10?

Link: http://neverwintervault.net/project/nwn1/prefab/item/rod-fast-buffing

I have tried the 1.69 critical rebuild and 1.71 community patch. It states the .mod file is corrupt or built in a newer version of the game.

Comment: That last line isn't really a question.  Stick to the issue you're running into, and focus on that; that's what we can help with.

Comment: I guess to rephrase the question - Is the Mod listed in the link compatible with the current GoG copy of Neverwinter NIghts Diamond (Build 1.69) on Windows 10?

Comment: That's perfect.  If you can edit the quesiton to focus on that, I think we've got ourselves a winner.

Comment: Thanks. I get a little verbose with my thoughts. Hopefully it is now clearer.

Answer (score 2):

I answered this question on my own in a complicated way. I am still waiting on other forums for an easier answer but I might as well post my solution here.

The issue is that the event loaders didn't actually load the scripts when you activate the item. The items are built to run on the x2_mod_def_act event which is not present in the original campaign.

To fix this I changed the module properties of each original campaign module to include a custom script that calls both the normal even loader for that module and "x2 mod def" scripts.

Here is the following process that I used.

Step 1: Edit your nwnplayer.ini with the following entries under the "Game Options" category. This will open all modules for editing in the NwN tooleset:

```
    CODEWORD=hacktastic
    CODEWORD XP1=ffrodriguez
    CODEWORD XP2=barkeater
```

Step 2: Open the toolset and then open the Campaign Modules option. The area we want is the "Edit > Module Properties > Events" menu. Listed are the two main features required to load this mod. Take note of what is listed in each. [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE2Y4.jpg):

```
OnActivateItem
OnModuleLoad
```

Step 3: If nothing is listed in either of those slots then you can fill them with the respective mod label

```
x2_mod_def_act for OnActivateItem
x2_mod_def_load for OnModuleLoad
```

Step 4: If something is already listed in those slots, such as m3q1modactivat, then you will need to load both the x2 script and the campaign script. To do this you will need to create a custom script. Right click on the scripts tree in the module and select "New". The new entry will need to call both event loaders with the ExecuteScript commands. [Here is a sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MgSC.jpg):

Step 5: Save the module edits that you made and you should be able to play through the original campaign with the the rod. To spawn it you will need to use the commands from the console (tilde key):
        DebugMode 1
        dm_spawnitem extrodfastcast

This needs to be done for each campaign chapter, unfortunately. It's about 10 minutes of work. There is probably a much easier solution. This also opens the door to conflicts to other mods that use the same loader as it will call them twice. It's dirty, but it works.

Comment: For most of the campaign modules, couldn't you just copy the pre-existing script for the OnActivateItem event to a new `nw_it_recall` script and then replace the OnActivateItem entry with `x2_mod_def_load`?

Comment: If you do take this route to add Tag-Based Scripting to your OC Modules, either make the change before you play through any part of the Module or [edit any pre-existing saves](https://forum.neverwintervault.org/t/adding-tag-based-scripting-to-oc-modules/1236/3?u=palswim) (with Leto or another tool), changing the Module variables `Mod_OnActivtItem` to `x2_mod_def_act` and `Mod_OnModLoad` to `x2_mod_def_load`.